# I have no idea what is wrong

Tags: google-apps-script

I have problem with this Google Apps Script code. It looks perfectly fine, but dosent work for some reason. Here is the code:

```
  var d = form.getItems(); //L: array of all items in form

  for(l = 0; l<d.length; l++){ //L: normal for-cycle
    form.deleteItem(l); //L: deleting all items in form
  }
```

I cant post images, but i can describe you what they look like:
It is always blank form with items, they were 6 at the begining.

1)It says Item1 to Item6
2)Item1, Item3, Item5
3)Item3

Than it goes again.

For some reason it only deletes half of items. The rest of the code wont be done ether.

I tried changing the varriable, i even used while. All the numbres are corrected, i double checked and different numbers dont work.

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
for(l = d.length-1; l>=0; l--){ 
    form.deleteItem(l); 
  }
```

Let's say **d** has 6 items [0,1,2,3,4,5]. Now when you delete your item **0**, **d** becomes this [0,1,2,3,4], therefore when you delete item **1** you delete the second item and etc. By deleting items from the end you avoid this issue.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped. Now it seems so easy :D Thank you